# how to fix "Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::class does not exist."

Tags: laravel, migration

When I use php artisan migrate I receive this message.
Can someone help me with this?
I searched on the Internet but I didn't find anything that helped me.
(I am new in laravel)

my table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateServiceTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('service', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('icon');
            $table->class('class');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('service');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$table->**class**('class'); // class not type .`

Answer (score 2):

Normally this happens if you use unknown/wrong data types.

In my case, this happened because I used 'int' instead of 'integer' (wrong data type).

Comment: Exactly, I the same to me! Until I've seen in PHPStorm the underline under the int...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Check the naming of your columns.

for me:

`$table->**name**("name")` instead of the right syntax which is

`$table->**string**("name")`

Into context: the above was because the referral was `$table->**class**("class")` instead of the right syntax `$table->**string**("class")`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

$table->**class**('class');
*class* is not the datatype, use String, char or other datatypes according to your requirements. Use the below link for the datatypes reference in Laravel

[Datatype reference](https://www.tkserver.com/laravel-database-column-types/)

Answer (score -2):

I have notice that this error is due to qoutes ('') in the nullable function
we have to write true or false in nullable  without qoutes For Example:

> `$table->string('name')->unique()->nullable('false');`

This above method is wrong we have to write the code just like below remove qoutes from nullable function

> `$table->string('name')->unique()->nullable(false);`